# prevent ttk::treeview from selecting on expanding/collapsing subtrees

Tags: treeview, tk-toolkit

so i'm having a simple treeview, with some expandible subtrees, and a listener for selection changes:

```
ttk::treeview .tree
pack .tree -expand 1 -fill both

.tree tag configure disabled -foreground grey
.tree tag bind all <<TreeviewSelect>> "puts selected"

set node [.tree insert {} end -text "Node 0" -tags all]
.tree insert $node end -text "A" -tags "all"
.tree insert $node end -text "B" -tags "all"
.tree insert $node end -text "C" -tags "all"
set node [.tree insert {} end -text "Node 1" -tags all -open 1]
.tree insert $node end -text "X" -tags "all"
.tree insert $node end -text "Y" -tags "all"
.tree insert $node end -text "Z" -tags "all"
```

It seems that tcl/tk will automatically (de)select a subtree-node ("Node 0" resp "Node 1") and call the `<<TreeviewSelect>>` listener, if the user tries to expand/collapse the subtree (by clicking on the Expander icon left of the node element).

Is there any way to allow expansion/callapsing of the subtree without selecting the item at the same time?

My dev platform is Tcl/Tk-8.6 (on Debian/stretch), but any solution is supposed to work cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works.

```
package require Tk

variable vars

proc sel { args } {
  variable vars
  if { $vars(skip) && $vars(oldsel) ne {} } {
    .tree selection set $vars(oldsel)
    set vars(skip) false
    return
  }
  set vars(skip) false
  set vars(oldsel) [.tree selection]
}
proc op { args } {
  variable vars
  set vars(skip) true
}
proc cl { args } {
  variable vars
  set vars(skip) true
}

ttk::treeview .tree
set id1 [.tree insert {} end -id id1 -text id1]
set id1-1 [.tree insert $id1 end -id id1-1 -text id1-1]
set id1-2 [.tree insert $id1 end -id id1-2 -text id1-2]
set id2 [.tree insert {} end -id id2 -text id2]
set id2-1 [.tree insert $id2 end -id id2-1 -text id2-1]
set id2-2 [.tree insert $id2 end -id id2-2 -text id2-2]
bind .tree <<TreeviewSelect>> sel
bind .tree <<TreeviewOpen>> op
bind .tree <<TreeviewClose>> cl
pack .tree

set vars(oldsel) {}
```

Comment: i don't really understand though, why you skip the skipping if the oldsel is not empty (as this will still exhibit the problem if there is currently *no* selection). and of course you could bind both `TreeviewOpen` and `TreeviewClose` to the same handler...

Comment: The selection can't be set to {} the very first time (doesn't exist, skip is false).  Of course, if you initialize `oldsel` to a default selection, you don't need that test.